# Encrypt String in Golang in UTF-8 to put in postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, encryption, utf-8

I am using crypto in go to take a password and use a passphrase to encrypt the password and then store it as a string in a postgres sql database. The encryption works fine but when I try to add it to my database I get an error that seems to indicate that going from a []byte to a string type messes up the encrypted password.

```
func Encrypt(password string, passphrase string) string {
    data := []byte(password)
    block, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(createHash(passphrase)))
    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
    if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    ciphertext := gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, data, nil)
    return string(ciphertext)
}

func createHash(key string) string {
    hasher := md5.New()
    hasher.Write([]byte(key))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
}
```

When I run this code and try to add the row in the database I get the error

```
ERROR #22021 invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"
```

I am just looking for an easy way in go to encrypt a string password and save the encrypted string into a table in postgres. The column in the table is of type VARCHAR but I am willing to change that as well if that is for some reason the issue. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Consider using a more secure password storage format such as [bcrypt](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt), [scrypt](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/scrypt) or [pbkdf2](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2).

Comment: @CeriseLimón The reason I used crypto was because I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt the password since it is used internally, from what I understand using a hash form like bcrypt is for storing information you don't need to decrypt but I could be totally wrong

Comment: You are correct that the password cannot be recovered from the hash used in the listed packages.

Comment: Unless you need to know what the literal contents of the password is later, there is no need to store it in some decrypt-able form. If you mean "password" in the usual sense, then storing it in a directly recoverable form is usually considered a red flag (which is probably why Cerise commented about it).

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to know the literal contents of the password since I pragmatically am using the password for another application that will grab the encrypted password from our db, decrypt it then use it to access another internal application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base64 encode it:

```
return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
```

Even though a string is a byte array, not all sequences of bytes are a valid UTF-8 string. Base64 encoding is commonly used to store binary data as text.